# Сумма чисел в строке (циклы, python3)

Tags: python, циклы

Дан список поговорок, ваша задача получить сумму чисел из каждой строки.
targets = ["7 раз отмерь, 1 раз отрежь.", "Не имей 100 рублей, а имей 100 друзей.", "1 за всех и все за 1."]

Вывод:
7 раз отмерь, 1 раз отрежь. 8
Не имей 100 рублей, а имей 100 друзей. 200
1 за всех и все за 1. 2

Пока так:

```
targets = ["7 раз отмерь, 1 раз отрежь.", "Не имей 100 рублей, а имей 100 друзей.", "1 за всех и все за 1."]
for letter in targets:
    print(letter)
```

Comment: Попробуйте для начала разбить предложение на части, хотя бы с помощью split

Comment: Т.е. пока ты ничего не сделал?

Answer (score 5):

я бы через регулярки делал бы - они позволяют очень легко находить все числа в строке

1. находит числа в виде строк
2. переводим строки в числа
3. считаем сумму

в итоге:

```
import re
targets = ["7 раз отмерь, 1 раз отрежь.", "Не имей 100 рублей, а имей 100 друзей.", "1 за всех и все за 1."]
for text in targets:
    res = sum(map(int, re.findall(r"\d+", text)))
    print(text, res)
```

Answer (score 4):

Написал 2 варианта, с регулярными выражениями и без, вдруг, может потом, что похитрее понадобится. Мне хоть и нравятся регулярки, но по времени будет значительно медленнее. Тут на вкус и цвет, как говорится

```
import re


def num_count(s):
    result = 0
    nums = re.findall(r"\d+", s)
    for n in nums:
        result += int(n)
    return result
```

Без регулярок:

```
def num_count(s):
    result = 0
    for i in s.split():
        if i.isdigit():
            result += int(i)
    return result
```

Comment: А вообще можно и в 1 строчку: num_count3 = lambda s: sum([int(i) for i in s.split() if i.isdigit()])

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку в заголовке вопроса `циклы`, сделал конкретно на циклах без re, split, int, generators и list comprehensions. Только олдскул :) [ну почти]

```
targets = ["7 раз отмерь, 1 раз отрежь.", "Не имей 100 рублей, а имей 100 друзей.", "1 за всех и все за 1."]
for phrase in targets:
    current_number = sum_phrase = 0
    for char in phrase:
        if char.isdigit():
            current_number = current_number * 10 + ord(char) - ord('0')
        else:
            sum_phrase += current_number
            current_number = 0
    print(f'\'{phrase}\' = {sum_phrase}')
```

```
'7 раз отмерь, 1 раз отрежь.' = 8
'Не имей 100 рублей, а имей 100 друзей.' = 200
'1 за всех и все за 1.' = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот решение:

```
def sumer_str(text):
    text = ' ' + text + ' '
    nums = '0123456789'
    res_arr = list()
    vb = False
    for index in text:
        if index in nums and not vb:
            vb = True
            res = str()
        elif index not in nums and vb:
            vb = False
            res_arr.append(int(res))
        if index in nums and vb:
            res+=index
    return sum(res_arr)
```

Comment: Я очень шокирован комьюнити данного сайта. ВЫ занижаете рейтинг вопроса и моего ответа но никто не предлогает решение. Стоит задуматься!

Comment: Ваше решение крайне громоздкое и не продуманное. Подумайте над тем чтоб дать качественное решение.

Comment: Но почему же ни вы, ни другой человек не предлагает решения?

Comment: Уже предложили решения выше

Comment: Я заметил, действительно возможно сделать короче, но к тем людям у меня притензий нету!